# Can I save a session in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to save sessions in Chrome? I'm a longtime Firefox user, and am used to being able to save a session containing multiple tabs so I can go back to it at any time. I'm trying to switch over to Chrome, but without this ability it's not going to happen.

I know that I can set the prefs to open the last-opened tabs at startup, but that's not really the same as true session management.

I'm perfectly happy to install an extension to do this if one exists.

Comment: Built-in functionality to save the currently open tabs: https://superuser.com/a/903666/303483

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) did the trick for me.

> Manage Your Browser Sessions
>
> - View and save the state of all open browser tabs in the current or past browser sessions.
> - Quickly restore your tabs and resume your web surfing after a browser or system crash.
> - Edit the sessions you've saved and restore them into the desired set of windows at any time.
> - Create a session from a list of URLs and export sessions to text or CSV format.
> - Consolidate sessions and eliminate duplicate tabs with ease.

Comment: Yes, while there are other [session extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search?category=ext&q=session), I swear by Session Buddy.

Comment: The Session Buddy link now seems to be broken, and searching the chrome web store for "session buddy" proved fruitless.

Comment: The link works for me. Also try http://sessionbuddy.com/

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention back to that. My guess is that the link was just temporarily down.

Comment: Hey is there a way to restore your sessions in sessionbuddy  if you cleared your cache/ internet files?  
Does it or google back up somewhere?

Comment: Session Buddy doesn't restore Tab Groups; Tabox does.

Answer (score 7):

A few options:

1. Built-in functionality. Go to Options (Basics tab) and choose "reopen the pages that were open last".
2. There are tons of extensions that allow you to do that
3. I love the [Panic Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/panicbutton/faminaibgiklngmfpfbhmokfmnglamcm) addon. It's a bit different, but allows me to save my session when I want to:

   > PanicButton makes it easier for you to hide all of your tabs at once just by clicking on a button. They are then saved as bookmarks in a separate folder. Afterwards, the PanicButton turns green and shows you how many tabs are currently hidden.

Comment: Note: I just did a quick search and it appears that Session Buddy looks promising.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko

Comment: Thanks, Session Buddy looks like what I need; the built-in Chrome function only allows you to open the last-open tabs, not save tabs and reopen them at any time.

Comment: Session Buddy currently fails to restore Tab Groups; Tabox does.

Answer (score 2):

[TabCloud](https://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=11&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=TabCloud) saves your tabs "onto the cloud" so you won't lose them even if your laptop is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save, open, and view sessions using only your keyboard:

[Ferro, the keyboard interface to Chrome](http://www.getferro.com/#sessions)

Comment: Hmmmm it looks like it's very interesting

Answer (score 1):

I use this Chrome app and it is very useful: [Simple bookmark](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-bookmark/mkflihhblndkoipfpkbaipibnojkefen).

You can save the current session or the URLs – whatever you like – and open the session you want with a single click.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend [Session Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mghenlmbmjcpehccoangkdpagbcbkdpc) when people ask me this question.

You can save multiple sessions with labels, modify existing sessions, and create temporary sessions.