# saving sessions on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, history

I have the habit of leaving windows to read later; sometimes have 10 open or more.    The tabs I have open just before closing are the ones I am interested in and have not finished reading.

Chrome will save your sessions with the **Recent Tabs** feature.  But what I if I want recent tabs from 10 days ago or a month ago?  Are there Chrome extensions that will save the tabs you have open at a given time?

History is convenient but a little too detailed.  Searching through my own history I can find that StachExchange question I liked from 5 days ago and weed through about 10 others that weren't relevant.

---

This feature may have existed in Firefox

- [Is there a method to export the URLs of the open tabs of a Firefox window?](https://superuser.com/questions/96739/is-there-a-method-to-export-the-urls-of-the-open-tabs-of-a-firefox-window)

Kind of related

- [Can I save a session in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/230042/can-i-save-a-session-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a "session saving" but you can save the currently open tabs as bookmarks.

To do so, press <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+D</kbd>*, create a separate folder (e.g., Sessions > 2015-04-20) and hit `Save`. This way, you can save tabs for different dates in different folders.

*Alternatively, you can press hamburger menu at the right top corner, then go to `Bookmarks > Bookmark open pages...`

Answer (score 1):

I think [Session Buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) is doing what you are looking for.