# Force Chrome to save its current session correctly

Tags: google-chrome

To start with, I'm on Windows 8.1 x64 running Chrome stable, v43.0.2357.124 32-bit (fully up-to-date as of this post). I have always had the option set for Chrome to "Continue where you left off" when starting, but lately this hasn't been working properly. It works strangely--I'll be browsing for a while, use various tabs, then close the window, and if I reopen it again a few minutes later it will reopen a random collection of tabs that I had open within the previous 5-10 minutes before I closed it. The tabs that I actually DID have open are always reopened, so that's not a problem, but Chrome is reopening *extra* tabs and it seems to be random as to which ones it chooses.

This is happening across several different computers, both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. One of the computers is my work computer and has an entirely different set of extensions/bookmarks and whatnot (it's not synced with everything else).

Is there anything else I can do, via extension or otherwise, to fix this local state saving issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I save a session in Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/230042/can-i-save-a-session-in-chrome)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is about how to save a session.  It appears that is not the issue here.  Rather, it's how to get the feature to work correctly.